# Csharp substring text and add it to list

Tags: c#, string, file, substring

I have file.txt like:
**EDIT: I didn't wrote but this is important i guess- In file.txt there can be  others lines!**

```
folder=c:\user;c:\test;c:\something;
```

I need to add one path like one list item (`List<string> Folders`).
So my List should looks like:

```
Folders[0] = c:\user
Folders[1] = c:\test
```

etc. (without text "folder=" which starts line in file.txt and ";" which means end of path).

file can contain much more paths.
I did something like this:

```
       using (FileStream fss = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fss))
            {

                while (sr.EndOfStream == false)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if(line.StartsWith("folders"))
                    { 
                       int index = line.IndexOf("=");
                       int index1 = line.IndexOf(";");
                       string folder = line.Substring(index + 1, index1 - (index + 1));
                       Folders.Add(folder);
```

Now in List Folders i have first path but what now? I can't go ahead :(

Comment: Why not? What's stopping you? You might just simplify this by trimming off `folder=` and splitting by `;`. Then you can just dump the whole split array into your list with `InsertRange`. Done.

Comment: Something like line.Trim(char["folders="]); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using(var sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    var folders = sr.ReadToEnd()
    .Split(new char[]{';','\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(o => o.Replace("folder=",""))
    .ToArray();
    Folders.AddRange(folders);
}
```

Comment: But how add each path to List now ?

Comment: You're assuming there's only one line in the file.  What if there are multiple lines that begin with "folder="?  What if there are other lines that shouldn't be processed?...

Comment: Actually, there are others lines. Sorry, i edit question.

Comment: @Kafus in your example was only one line. I don't know, how other looks like

Comment: Great! this is what i need :) i should only replace `sr.ReadToEnd()` to my variable `line` and everything is working. Thanks a lot

Comment: Now you might get values from other lines that have also values separated by semi-colons, but do **NOT** begin with "folder=".  For instance, if there is a line like this: `names=bob;george;john;`.

Comment: this is why i need to replace `sr.ReadToEnd()` to `line`. I think it will be ok.

Comment: This will also incorrectly change a path that has "folder=" as part of its name: `folder=c:\some_path\folder=name\other_part;`.  The middle part will get changed because you've done a blanket `Replace()`.

Comment: hmm.. but in my code, first of all, I'm looking for correct line: `if (line.StartsWith("folders")` then i'm reading this line and then spliting, substringing etc.

Comment: That might be true for you, **kafus**, but I'm talking about the code posted **here** in this answer, which has been accepted as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code, using File.ReadAllText

```
            string Filepath = "c:\abc.txt";
            string filecontent = File.ReadAllText(Filepath);
            string startingString = "=";
            var startIndex = filecontent.IndexOf(startingString);
            filecontent = filecontent.Substring(startIndex + 1, filecontent.Length - startIndex - 2);
            List<String> folders = filecontent.Split(';').ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example:

```
    List<String> Folders = new List<string>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Users\mikes\Documents\SomeFile.txt";

        string folderTag = "folder=";
        using (FileStream fss = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fss))
            {
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (line.StartsWith(folderTag))
                    {
                        line = line.Substring(folderTag.Length); // remove the folderTag from the beginning
                        Folders.AddRange(line.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach(string folder in Folders)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(folder);
        }
    }
```

I'd use this approach if you're going to read line by line, and do something else based on what each line starts with.  In that case you could add different `else if(...)` blocks:

```
                    if (line.StartsWith(folderTag))
                    {
                        line = line.Substring(folderTag.Length); // remove the folderTag from the beginning
                        Folders.AddRange(line.Split(";".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
                    }
                    else if(line.StartsWith("parameters="))
                    {
                        // do something different with a line starting with "parameters="
                    }
                    else if (line.StartsWith("unicorns="))
                    {
                        // do something else different with a line starting with "unicorns="
                    }
```

Comment: yes, i have something like this in my code. I mean `else if`. Thanks a lot.